# Delaying Update() with Invoke

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to delay the effects of a script that is attached to a game object?

I have 2 characters in a scene, both receiving live motion capture data, so they are both animated identically. I have rotated one by 180 degrees and placed it in front of the other one, to create the impression that they are copying/mirroring each other. Each has several scripts attached to them, of course.

Now, I would like to be able to delay one character a bit (e.g. 1 sec) to make it look more realistic, as if one character is observing the other character and then copying its exact movements.

I am trying to achieve this by **buffering** the animation data (network data) that reaches the second character. Below, is the code snippet that animates the 1st character **immediately**:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3[] latestPositions;
    Quaternion[] latestOrientations;

    if (mvnActors.getLatestPose(actorID-1, out latestPositions, out latestOrientations))
    {
            updateMvnActor(currentPose, latestPositions, latestOrientations);
            updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);
    }
}
```

And below, is the code snippet that is supposed to animate the 2nd character but in fact there is no movement at all:

```
private Queue<Vector3[]> posQueue;
private Queue<Quaternion[]> rotQueue;

void Start()
{
    posQueue = new Queue<Vector3[]>();
    rotQueue = new Queue<Quaternion[]>();
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3[] latestPositions;
    Quaternion[] latestOrientations;

    if (mvnActors.getLatestPose(actorID-1, out latestPositions, out latestOrientations))
    {
        posQueue.Enqueue(latestPositions);
        rotQueue.Enqueue(latestOrientations);

        if ((posQueue.Count > 10) && (rotQueue.Count > 10))
        {
            Vector3[] delayedPos = posQueue.Peek();
            Quaternion[] delayedRot = rotQueue.Peek();

            updateMvnActor(currentPose, delayedPos, delayedRot);
            updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't `peek` supposed to provide the 1st element in the queue, which here would be the one in the 11th place? Or is it because queue is not suitable for heavy animation updating?

EDIT: SOLVED

Added `int delayedFrames = 30;` to class variables (to replace number 10) and used `Dequeue` instead of `Peek`.

Comment: As far as I know you can't delay the Update, can you maybe attach the code in the Update you're trying to delay?

Comment: @ILiveForVR Thanks for your comment. My update contains 2 more updating methods, that re-write the latest animation pose of the Unity characters, each calling a few other updating functions. I will edit the question with my update code...

Comment: I think you might have to buffer the Motion Capture Data and somehow feed it to the second character with a delay.

Comment: @Tim Pohlmann That is exactly the term I was looking for!  BUFFER!  Thanks for your comment.  Do you know how I can do that?  A couple of suggestions would be to use `WaitForSeconds` or `Invoke` but as you can imagine, after the delay, the second character will pick up from exactly where the live motion data is coming in, so buffering the data is precisely what I am after...

Comment: @Jtech I updated my answer with a buffer like thing. Could you maybe try it out? I hope it works for you!

Comment: @ILiveForVR Perfect, thank you. I started experimenting with a queue, but my 2nd character freezes. I will add my code in an update, so please kindly take a look again and see if you can spot what I am doing wrong. Or I should use a `list`?

Comment: I'd never heard of a queue in c#, that seems like a way better solution to your problem! Looking forward your code

Comment: I added the relevant bits of the code, but the second character (that has a separate script attached to it) would not move...

Comment: Maybe try Dequeue instead of peek? Peek appears to return the entire queue while dequeue returns and removes the first item in the queue. Which I think is what you want

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help. It works!  It does exactly what I want!  Cheers for following up and not giving up on helping...

Comment: @Tim Pohlmann Your initial "buffering" suggestion solved my dilemma! Thank you

Comment: @Jtech Yes! So glad it works! You're more than welcome!

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for your comment. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Answer to @JTech's question isn't complete in this answer, look at the comments underneath his/her question for the final solution

I personally dislike WaitForSeconds, it has slowed my game way down once. 
Try something like:

```
public List<Vector3[]> PreviousPositions;
public List<Quaternion[]> PreviousRotations;
private Vector3[] latestPositions;
private Quaternion[] latestOrientations;


void Start(){
    PreviousPositions = new List<Vector3[]>();
    PreviousRotations = new List<Quaternion[]>();
}


void Update(){
    if (mvnActors.getLatestPose(actorID-1, out latestPositions, out latetOrientations))
    {
        updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);

        //Add the position and rotationstuff to the 'buffer' lists here
        Invoke("DoStuff", 1); 

    }
}


void DoStuff(){
    updateMvnActor(currentPose, PreviousPositions[0] , PreviousRotations[0]);
    PreviousPositions.RemoveAt(0);
    PreviousRotations.RemoveAt(0);

}

OnApplicationQuit(){
    CancelInvoke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delay the `Update` method.

What you can use is [WaitForSeconds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html), or you can test if 1 sec passed with an `if` statement based on `Time`.

Then execute the code to move the second character.

**EDIT**

I think a simple timer will do the job but you will need to take in account the 1 sec time when getting the latest positions/orientations.

```
public float delay = 1.0f;

private float timer = 0;

void Update()
{
    Vector3[] latestPositions;
    Quaternion[] latestOrientations;

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer >= delay) 
    {
        if (mvnActors.getLatestPose(actorID-1, out latestPositions, out latestOrientations))
        {
            updateMvnActor(currentPose, latestPositions, latestOrientations);
            updateModel(currentPose, targetModel);
        }

        timer = 0;
    }    
}
```

Otherwise you can use [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) with a delay as a parameter to repeat a method every X seconds.

To take only the actions made before the delay, you can register the time at the moment when it's done, 'remove' the actions made during the delay and take the actions made before it.

Or register the number of actions made by the first character during the delay and remove the same number of actions - the last ones - to your update on the second character. (seems easier/more simple)

Like this, I assume the second character will not do the last actions made during the delay, but will do it after.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a good solution. Please see my added code. Do you mean I could just add in the if statement that is already there a simple timer? The motion data is streaming live into Unity, so after one second, the Update will start, but still use the exact data that is coming in at that moment, which is what going into the first character. Or maybe I did not understand you correctly?

Comment: @Jtech I updated my post with the timer code, say if it can help you or if I miss something.

Comment: Thanks man. I realized that after the delay, the second character will pick up from exactly where the live motion data is coming in anyway, so after the delay both will again be animated identically. I am working on a buffering mechanism to see if I can queue up the network data. I will edit my question with an update, so I would appreciate your taking another look at it please. Cheers

Comment: Hi, I used your suggestion elsewhere for delaying purposes. In the question I posted, I used buffering to delay the same data that animates a 1st avatar. Cheers